# How to command "Ping" display time and date of ping

Tags: command-line, ping

When I ping I have this display:

```
> ping -i 4 www.google.fr 
64 bytes from wi-in-f94.1e100.net (173.194.67.94): icmp_seq=503 ttl=46 time=45.5 ms
.......
.......
64 bytes from wi-in-f94.1e100.net (173.194.67.94): icmp_seq=508 ttl=46 time=44.9 ms
64 bytes from wi-in-f94.1e100.net (173.194.67.94): icmp_seq=509 ttl=46 time=45.1 ms
```

I'd like to have the time of the ping before.

Something like:

```
> (right functions) + ping -i 7 www.google.fr 
mardi 15 mai 2012, 10:29:06 (UTC+0200) - 64 bytes from wi-in-f94.1e100.net (173.194.67.94): icmp_seq=503 ttl=46 time=45.5 ms
.......
.......
mardi 15 mai 2012, 10:29:13 (UTC+0200) - 64 bytes from wi-in-f94.1e100.net (173.194.67.94): icmp_seq=508 ttl=46 time=44.9 ms
mardi 15 mai 2012, 10:29:20 (UTC+0200) - 64 bytes from wi-in-f94.1e100.net (173.194.67.94): icmp_seq=509 ttl=46 time=45.1 ms
```

How would you do this in a command line (if it's possible)?

Comment: Generic version – [Is there a Unix utility to prepend timestamps to stdin?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21564/95735)

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Use:

```
ping www.google.fr | while read pong; do echo "$(date): $pong"; done
```

You will get the result like this:

[image]

Comment: Wow very nice. And helpful to learn shell stuff. Thank you!

Comment: Uptime in seconds `ping 192.168.70.1 | while read pong; do echo "$(awk '{print $1}' /proc/uptime): $pong"; done`

Comment: Very nice trick :)

Comment: is there a way to get more desimals for seconds, something like mon jan 14 10:51:29.231778 ? I would like to have exactly different time stamp for each ping line

Comment: @NicolasMolano, on my system I can get nanosecond precision by changing `$(date)` to `$(date -Ins)`.

Answer (score 26):

### 1. time from `ping -D`

Another possibility to  use the **`ping -D`** option which gets you the timestamp as Unix time.

```
tilo@t-ubuntu:~$ ping google.com -D
PING google.com (173.194.33.73) 56(84) bytes of data.
[1388886989.442413] 64 bytes from sea09s15-in-f9.1e100.net (173.194.33.73): icmp_req=1 ttl=57 time=11.1 ms
[1388886990.443845] 64 bytes from sea09s15-in-f9.1e100.net (173.194.33.73): icmp_req=2 ttl=57 time=11.0 ms
[1388886991.445200] 64 bytes from sea09s15-in-f9.1e100.net (173.194.33.73): icmp_req=3 ttl=57 time=10.8 ms
[1388886992.446617] 64 bytes from sea09s15-in-f9.1e100.net (173.194.33.73): icmp_req=4 ttl=57 time=10.9 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 10.860/11.005/11.139/0.123 ms
tilo@t-ubuntu:~$
```

here is a `awk` cmd to parse timestamp to date format:

```sh
$ ping -D 10.1.1.1 | awk '{ if(gsub(/\[|\]/, "", $1)) $1=strftime("[%F %T]", $1); print}'
PING 10.1.1.1 (10.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
[2020-04-10 19:25:08] 64 bytes from 10.1.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=14.1 ms
[2020-04-10 19:25:09] 64 bytes from 10.1.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=12.9 ms
[2020-04-10 19:25:10] 64 bytes from 10.1.1.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=63 time=12.0 ms
^C
```

PS: awk may full-buffered with pipe, a `fflush()` after `print` will fix:

```sh
ping.ts(){
    if [ -t 1 ]; then
        ping -D "$@" | awk '{ if(gsub(/\[|\]/, "", $1)) $1=strftime("[\033[34m%F %T\033[0m]", $1); print; fflush()}'
    else
        ping -D "$@" | awk '{ if(gsub(/\[|\]/, "", $1)) $1=strftime("[%F %T]", $1); print; fflush()}'
    fi  
}
```

### 2. time from `date`

Here a version of "Achu" command with slightly different format:

```
ping www.google.com -i 10 -c 3000 | while read pong; do echo "$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S): $pong"; done >PingTest_2014-01-04.log
```

That gets you:

```
2014-01-04_175748: 64 bytes from sea09s16-in-f19.1e100.net (173.194.33.115): icmp_req=13 ttl=57 time=10.5 ms
```

Answer (score 24):

There is a utility called `ts`, which reads stdin, adds timestamps, and writes it to stdout:

```
me@my-laptop:~$ ping localhost | ts
Nov 08 09:15:41 PING localhost (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
Nov 08 09:15:41 64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.060 ms
Nov 08 09:15:42 64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.098 ms
Nov 08 09:15:43 64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.082 ms
Nov 08 09:15:44 64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.091 ms
```

It can be installed in Ubuntu with `sudo apt install moreutils`.

Comment: +1 Just as a sidenote - ts is not installed in Ubuntu (at least 16.04) by default, so you need to install it as `apt install moreutils`

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [`gawk`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/gawk.1.html) (or `awk`, if your [`/etc/alternatives/awk`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/484561/what-is-etc-alternatives-used-for) points to `/usr/bin/gawk`):

```bash
ping -c 4 www.google.fr | gawk '{print strftime("%c: ") $0}'
```

This is similar to the approach in [Achu's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/137246/22949), but `ping`'s output is piped to `gawk` instead of a shell loop that calls `date`. As with that approach, it works without `-c`, but if you don't pass `-c n` to make ping stop after ***n*** pings, and you stop the loop with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, `ping` won't print the usual statistics.

```
ek@Io:~$ ping -c 4 www.google.fr | gawk '{print strftime("%c: ") $0}'
Tue 03 Jan 2017 10:09:51 AM EST: PING www.google.fr (216.58.193.99) 56(84) bytes of data.
Tue 03 Jan 2017 10:09:51 AM EST: 64 bytes from sea15s08-in-f3.1e100.net (216.58.193.99): icmp_seq=1 ttl=51 time=327 ms
Tue 03 Jan 2017 10:09:52 AM EST: 64 bytes from sea15s08-in-f3.1e100.net (216.58.193.99): icmp_seq=2 ttl=51 time=302 ms
Tue 03 Jan 2017 10:09:53 AM EST: 64 bytes from sea15s08-in-f3.1e100.net (216.58.193.99): icmp_seq=3 ttl=51 time=282 ms
Tue 03 Jan 2017 10:09:54 AM EST: 64 bytes from sea15s08-in-f3.1e100.net (216.58.193.99): icmp_seq=4 ttl=51 time=349 ms
Tue 03 Jan 2017 10:09:54 AM EST:
Tue 03 Jan 2017 10:09:54 AM EST: --- www.google.fr ping statistics ---
Tue 03 Jan 2017 10:09:54 AM EST: 4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3003ms
Tue 03 Jan 2017 10:09:54 AM EST: rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 282.035/315.227/349.166/25.398 ms
```

```
ek@Io:~$ ping www.google.fr | gawk '{print strftime("%c: ") $0}'
Tue 03 Jan 2017 10:10:35 AM EST: PING www.google.fr (216.58.193.99) 56(84) bytes of data.
Tue 03 Jan 2017 10:10:35 AM EST: 64 bytes from sea15s08-in-f99.1e100.net (216.58.193.99): icmp_seq=1 ttl=51 time=305 ms
Tue 03 Jan 2017 10:10:35 AM EST: 64 bytes from sea15s08-in-f99.1e100.net (216.58.193.99): icmp_seq=2 ttl=51 time=365 ms
Tue 03 Jan 2017 10:10:36 AM EST: 64 bytes from sea15s08-in-f99.1e100.net (216.58.193.99): icmp_seq=3 ttl=51 time=390 ms
Tue 03 Jan 2017 10:10:38 AM EST: 64 bytes from sea15s08-in-f99.1e100.net (216.58.193.99): icmp_seq=4 ttl=51 time=824 ms
Tue 03 Jan 2017 10:10:38 AM EST: 64 bytes from sea15s08-in-f99.1e100.net (216.58.193.99): icmp_seq=5 ttl=51 time=287 ms
^C
```

This happens whether `ping`'s output is piped to `gawk` or a shell `while` loop. The reason is that command on the right side of the pipe, rather than `ping`, receives [SIGINT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal#SIGINT) when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is pressed, and `ping` does not know to print the statistics before being terminated.

If you have run `ping` without `-c` on the left side of a pipe (as shown above) and you want to terminate it in such a way that it still prints the statistics, then instead of pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in the terminal where it is running, you could run `kill -INT PID` from another terminal, replacing *`PID`* with the process ID of the `ping` command. If you're only running one instance of `ping` then you could simply use `killall -INT ping`.

Alternatively, you could replace the `ping` command on the left side of the pipe [with a command](https://serverfault.com/a/903631/99345) that runs a shell, reports the process ID of that shell, and then replaces that shell with the `ping` command (causing it to have the same PID):

```bash
sh -c 'echo $$; exec ping www.google.fr' | gawk '{print strftime("%c: ") $0}'
```

Then the first line of output, will show the process ID of the `ping` command (which will typically be different each time). It would look like this, but with a different time and date and probably a different process ID:

```
Tue 20 Mar 2018 12:11:13 PM EDT: 7557
```

Then, from another terminal, you can run `kill -INT 7557`, replacing `7557` with the actual process ID you saw, to terminate the `ping` command in such a way as to cause it to print statistics.

(If you take advantage of your shell's [job control](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Job-Control) features, then you can achieve this within the same terminal, too. But if you want to copy text from your terminal without having to remove any extranous part where you ran commands in that terminal, then you should terminate `ping` from a separate terminal.)

Further reading:

- [Alin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19541387/1038860) to [How to derive current date and time and append at the end of each line that contain 'Hello'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12366995/how-to-derive-current-date-and-time-and-append-at-the-end-of-each-line-that-cont) on Stack Overflow.
- [9.1.5 Time Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html) in [Gawk: Effective AWK Programming](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/) (Gawk's official reference manual).
- [`man ping`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/ping.1.html) - "*When the specified number of packets have been sent (and received) or if the program is terminated with a SIGINT, a brief summary is displayed.*"

Comment: is there a way to send ctrl+c to ping first?

Comment: @atti Yes, you can send `SIGINT` (which is what pressing Ctrl+C does) to the `ping` process specifically, using `kill` or `killall`. I've expanded this answer with details.

Comment: Nice use of awk. +1

Answer (score 2):

```
ping google.in | xargs -n1 -i bash -c 'echo `date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`" {}"'
```

If your interested in saving it in file, then type the below command in the terminal

```
ping google.in | xargs -n1 -i bash -c 'echo `date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`" {}"' >> "/home/name_of_your_computer/Desktop/Ping_Test.txt"
```

You don't need to create any text files, it'll automatically do

**Ping_Test.txt**

```
2018-04-19 15:35:53 PING google.in (216.58.203.164) 56(84) bytes of data.
2018-04-19 15:35:53 64 bytes from bom07s11-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.203.164): icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=23.0 ms
2018-04-19 15:35:53 64 bytes from bom07s11-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.203.164): icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=38.8 ms
2018-04-19 15:35:54 64 bytes from bom07s11-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.203.164): icmp_seq=3 ttl=57 time=32.6 ms
2018-04-19 15:35:55 64 bytes from bom07s11-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.203.164): icmp_seq=4 ttl=57 time=22.2 ms
2018-04-19 15:35:56 64 bytes from bom07s11-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.203.164): icmp_seq=5 ttl=57 time=22.1 ms
2018-04-19 15:35:59 64 bytes from bom07s11-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.203.164): icmp_seq=7 ttl=57 time=23.6 ms
2018-04-19 15:36:00 64 bytes from bom07s11-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.203.164): icmp_seq=8 ttl=57 time=22.6 ms
2018-04-19 15:36:01 64 bytes from bom07s11-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.203.164): icmp_seq=9 ttl=57 time=22.3 ms
2018-04-19 15:36:02 64 bytes from bom07s11-in-f4.1e100.net (216.58.203.164): icmp_seq=10 ttl=57 time=26.3 ms
```

Comment: Is there a way to specify the number of times the ping command should be executed?

Answer (score -1):

(thanks to Achu and Eliah Kagan for the ideas)
there's a way to

- add time to `ping` output
- keep footnotes of `ping`
- and terminate this whole construction with `ctrl+c`

to do this one should instruct right part of the command (after the pipe) to ignore `SIGINT` using `trap "" INT`:

```
$ ping www.google.fr | bash -c 'trap "" INT; awk "{print strftime(\"%c - \") \$0}"'  
lun 26 Mar 2018 22:05:08 +0300 - PING www.google.fr (173.194.73.94) 56(84) bytes of data.
lun 26 Mar 2018 22:05:08 +0300 - 64 bytes from lq-in-f94.1e100.net (173.194.73.94): icmp_seq=1 ttl=47 time=19.6 ms
lun 26 Mar 2018 22:05:09 +0300 - 64 bytes from lq-in-f94.1e100.net (173.194.73.94): icmp_seq=2 ttl=47 time=20.1 ms
^Clun 26 Mar 2018 22:05:09 +0300 - 
lun 26 Mar 2018 22:05:09 +0300 - --- www.google.fr ping statistics ---
lun 26 Mar 2018 22:05:09 +0300 - 2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1000ms
lun 26 Mar 2018 22:05:09 +0300 - rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 19.619/19.866/20.114/0.284 ms
```