# What is etc/alternatives used for?

Tags: etc

What does `/etc/alternatives` stand for? How and why is it used?

I found `gnome-tex-editor` in `/usr/bin` which is linked as follows:

```
/usr/bin/gnome-text-editor -> /etc/alternatives/gnome-text-editor
/etc/alternatives/gnome-text-editor -> /usr/bin/gedit
```

So `gedit` and `gnome-text-editor` seem to be the same thing.

So why are some commands (e.g.: `gedit` and `gnome-text-editor`) provided twice?

And **what is the use** of `/etc/alternatives/` - how does it work?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

There are some programs that are considered generic. Many programs can provide the required functionality.

For example, `view` is one such meta-program that can be provided by any tool capable of displaying text, such as `more`,`less`,`vim`,etc.

**`/etc/alternatives` is a directory that is used in keeping track of the alternatives currently in use, by a tool called `update-alternatives`.**

For more information, read the [manual page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man8/update-alternatives.8.html) by `man update-alternatives` in a terminal. Also visit [Debian Alternatives System](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives).

Comment: As an example for how to use it, I had a problem that `nvim` was hijacking `vim` (I probably did it a long time ago) and now wanted to use `vim`. I first ran `update-alternatives --query vim`, which is very helpful it showed that it would link to `vim.basic`, but that `nvim` was the default. Then I ran `update-alternatives --remove vim /usr/bin/nvim`, this now meant that vim would link to `/usr/bin/vim.basic` which is what I wanted.