# How to command “hping3” display time and date of hping3

Tags: networking, command-line

When I hping3 I have this output:

```
hping3 -S -p 80 google.com    HPING google.com (eth0 89.25.120.57): S
set, 40 headers + 0 data bytes     

len=46 ip=89.25.120.57 ttl=62 id=40422 sport=80 flags=SA seq=0
win=29200 rtt=3.9 ms    

len=46 ip=89.25.120.57 ttl=62 id=41026 sport=80 flags=SA seq=1
win=29200 rtt=7.8 ms  len=46 ip=89.25.120.57 ttl=62 id=41341 sport=80
flags=SA seq=2 win=29200 rtt=3.7 ms ^C

--- google.com hping statistic --- 3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0% packet loss round-trip min/avg/max = 3.7/5.1/7.8 ms
```

I would like to have a date in front of each line:
Something like [How to command "Ping" display time and date of ping](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137233/how-to-command-ping-display-time-and-date-of-ping)

Can anyone help with this ?

Answer (score 1):

I've made it work.

hping3 is buffering the output. So in order to fix it I installed `expect` (`sudo apt-get install expect`) on Ubuntu 16.04 and then ran the following command:

```
$ unbuffer hping3 -S -p 80 google.com | while read pong; do echo "$(date): $pong"; done

Wed Nov  2 12:48:29 UTC 2016: HPING google.com (ens160 172.217.23.14):
S set, 40 headers + 0 data bytes

Wed Nov  2 12:48:29 UTC 2016: len=46 ip=172.217.23.14 ttl=58 id=35798
sport=80 flags=SA seq=0 win=42900 rtt=7.9 ms

Wed Nov  2 12:48:30 UTC 2016: len=46 ip=172.217.23.14 ttl=58 id=44519
sport=80 flags=SA seq=1 win=42900 rtt=7.9 ms

Wed Nov  2 12:48:31 UTC 2016: len=46 ip=172.217.23.14 ttl=58 id=43418
sport=80 flags=SA seq=2 win=42900 rtt=3.8 ms

Wed Nov  2 12:48:32 UTC 2016: len=46 ip=172.217.23.14 ttl=58 id=9116
sport=80 flags=SA seq=3 win=42900 rtt=7.7 ms
```